# How does dots per inch unit works in android?

Tags: android

1dp is one pixel for a display with a ppi of 160. Why does changing that to a small number (0.3) does not change the visibility? I was expecting that changing 1dp to 0.3 dp will make the widget(just a line) invisible.

Comment: but, did you really checked on a 160dpi device? I think, values are just rounded of to nearest pixels.

Answer (score 0):

In android there is a formula:

> `px = (int)(scale * dp + 0.5)`

(i.e. the device density scale rounded to the nearest whole pixel value)

The scale value would be based on the screen density of the device:

So `0.5dp` would result in `{1px, 1px, 1px, 2px}` for the above densities, whereas `1dp` would be `{1px, 2px, 2px, 3px}`. A tiny value like `0.1dp` would resolve to `{1px, 1px, 1px, 1px}` because anything less than 1 in the above formula resolves to a single pixel unless the value was explicitly `0dp` (it's not possible to draw something thinner than a single pixel width).

If you want to ensure that thinnest possible width is used, probably best to define the width explicitly with `px` instead of a scaled unit like `dp.` Setting a value of `1px` will draw with a single pixel on all devices, and is much more readable than hoping `0.5dp` or `0.1dp` does the same.

For more details read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)